# react router: navigate to the same component, with or without ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to navigate to the same route, with or without an id?

I have a table and when the row is clicked the user is navigated with a user id (will populate form with data fetched via id)
I also have a button to navigate the user to same page but without an id (populates empty form)

```
<Route path={[`${ROUTES.form}/:id`]}>>
  <Form />
</Route>
```

```js
const handleNavigateToForm = (data: any) => {
  history.push(`${ROUTES.Form}/${data.id}`);
};

const addNewFormOnClick = () => {
  history.push(`${ROUTES.Form}/`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `react-router@5` `Route` component's [`path`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) prop accepts path strings that [path-to-regexp@^1.7.0](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) understands. You can mark a path segment as [optional](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string):

```
<Route path={`${ROUTES.form}/:id?`} component={Form} />
```

The path can also take an array of paths, you could specify multiple paths you want to match with a single `Route`:

```
<Route
  path={[`${ROUTES.form}/:id`, ROUTES.form]} // *
  component={Form}
/>
```

<sup>*</sup>Note: order the paths from *more* specific to *less* specific.

Answer (score -1):

It is able to set the path as optional if you're using the newest react-router version (now is v6.14):

```
<Route  
  path="/form/:id?"
  element={<Form />}
/>
```

So the user will be direct to the same `Form` component either url includes `id` or not.

Another way to reach the goal is to use [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes) to nest the routes. If you need some specific component display with `<Form />`, it's worthy to try this:

```
<Route 
  path="/form"
  element={<Form />}
>
  <Route
    path=":id"
    element={<SomeSpecificComponent />}
  />
</Route>
```

and in the `<Form>` component:

```
const Form = () => {
  return (
    // some other elements
    <Outlet /> // This will display <SomeSpecificComponent /> if the url path is /form/:id
    // some other elements
  )
}
```

It's very convenient to separate two components.